# using distanceFromLocation to calculate nearest 5 locations effeciently

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I have around 2500 records in my `SQLite` database, each record represents a branch of a well known store in our country, I use `distanceFromLocation` to compare distance between the current user's location and a given location like this:

```
CLLocation* storeLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon];
double distance = [userLocation distanceFromLocation:storeLocation];
```

how to use this piece of code (**WITH AN EFFICIENT WAY THAT DOES NOT FREEZE UP THE UI**) to find the nearest 5 branches among 2500 `lat/lon` pairs stored in the local `SQLite` database ?

**EDIT :**

[the code here](http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=71) is an excellent example of how to calculate the distance between two points on the database level, so it's very efficient, but however, the code is kinda hard to be implemented 'coz it accesses SQLite and creates queries manually, anybody provides me with a working sample for that code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you narrow the search per region/ state?

Comment: Check out this (efficient) answer and the comment of Kenny Winker:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6828849/1611723

Comment: that's so difficult, each store record in the DB is related to a district, the country is divided into main districts, but there is no way to know in which district the current user is right now!

Comment: I will second Baptiste Alexandre suggestion; querying the DB is very fast

Comment: @BaptisteAlexandre that was an excellent example on the DB level, however, implementing Dave's code (on that page) has many issues and not as easy as you think since he accesses SQLite directly with manual queries.

Comment: @BaptisteAlexandre please post the link to that example as an answer and will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this (efficient) answer and the comment of Kenny Winker:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6828849/1611723

It was a similar problem and will help you.

Answer (score 3):

However you want to do it, to avoid blocking the UI you have to do this in another thread. You can achieve this in multiple ways. Here's an example with GCD:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSArray *closestFive = [self closestFive];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         //Tell yourself something when the process finished
         [self closestAre:closestFive];
    }
});
```

[self closestFive] could be naively implemented by looping through the locations, calculating distance, storing them in a dictionary using the CLLocation wrapped in an NSValue as key. Sort that, and return the subarrayWithRange: of that array. There are probably better implementations, but for 2500 elements, which is not that many, this way of doing it will suffice, as long as you do it in a background thread

This could be an implementation of it:

```
- (NSArray *)closestFive:(CLLocation *)location from:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSMutableArray *distances = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:locations.count];

    for (CLLocation *l in locations) {
        NSDictionary *d = @{
            @"location" : l,
            @"distance" : @([location distanceFromLocation:l])
        };
        [distances addObject:d];
    }
    [distances sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        double d1 = [obj1[@"distance"] doubleValue];
        double d2 = [obj1[@"distance"] doubleValue];

        if (d1 > d2) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        else if (d1 < d2) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }];
    return [[distances subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 5)] valueForKey:@"location"];
}
```